# List displaying only first record using jstl in jsp

Tags: spring, jstl

[image]

My List  in spring controller is as shown.

I am trying to display the records in jsp as.

```
  <c:forEach items="${myList}" var="myList">
        <tr>
            <td>${myList[0].submittedOn}</td> 
            <td>${myList[0].title}</td>    
        </tr>
   </c:forEach>
```

When I do this it prints only the first row, and I need to display all rows in jsp.

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="myList">
        <tr>
            <td>${myList.submittedOn}</td> 
            <td>${myList.title}</td>    
        </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

forgot to put the taglib

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The list index needs to be dynamic, you've got it hard-coded to be 0 so it will always be the first item in the list.  Also, I would name the item variable something different than your list variable.  Here's an example that should work:

`<c:forEach items="${myList}" var="item" varStatus="loopStatus">
    <tr>
        <td>${myList[loopStatus.index].submittedOn}</td> 
        <td>${myList[loopStatus.index].title}</td>

    </tr>
</c:forEach>`

An even easier way would be to just use the item variable instead of using a loop index at all, like this:

`<c:forEach var="item" items="${myList}">
    <tr>
        <td>${item.submittedOn}</td> 
        <td>${item.title}</td>

    </tr>
</c:forEach>`